# Where is ConcurrentQueue TryDequeue implementation

Tags: c#

Where can I see the actual code that performs the heavy lifting on TryDequeue?  I tried F12 (Go To Definition) but just the method name and parameters.

```
lock (this)
{
    T overflow;
    while (q.Count > Limit && q.TryDequeue(out overflow)) ;
}
```

Comment: This is not how you are supposed to use `ConcurrentQueue`. Don't lock and don't check its count. Just dequeue and use the value if `TryDeque` returns `true`

Comment: If I don't check the count then in every iteration an item is added and then removed for a net zero items. I did remove the count but not no items build up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentQueue.cs,601). Highly recommend not locking around a `ConcurrentQueue`, it defeats the purpose. A `Queue` will be much faster in that case.

Answer (score 1):

`ConcurrentQueue` is a class of the .NET framework. As such, it is available on your system as a binary in the global assembly cache. That means it comes without source code. In the title of your tab you will see the remark *[from metadata]*, which means it is auto-generated source.

You can check the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentQueue.cs) online, which is provided by Microsoft. You can also use a decompiler like *ILSpy* or *reflector*.